# Get max value in a list of points

Tags: c#, .net

I have a list of points, each point defined as an object of type "XYPoint", with X and Y members.
How do I find a point with max X or max Y value in the list of points, short of looping (Linq?)?

```
public class XYPoint
{
    int X;
    int Y;
}
List<XYPoint> lsRawPoints;
```

Comment: what have you tried?  Also what do you mean by max point.  Which is more max (4,2) or (2,4)?

Comment: Well have you *tried* using LINQ yet? Have you looked at the `Max` method? Note that currently your `X` and `Y` fields are private - are they actually private fields in your class, or are they public properties?

Comment: I am not familiar with Linq but I thought that would be more efficient than looping. If have a list of XYPoint objects with X and Y. I need to get the max X and Max Y. So in your example of (4,2) and (2,4) it would be MaxX = 4 and MaxY = 4.

Comment: You still haven't said what you want (since max is not defined for class XYPoint.)  But the what makes linq more effient is that it is lazy.  I don't think you can do that here but I don't know for sure without knowing what you mean by Max

Comment: I sometimes don't get your downvoting schemes! I asked the question that people understood and responded. It is a legitimate question, why down vote?? I have a list of points, each point defined as an object with x and y values and I need to be able to find a point with x value higher than others. How can this be unclear (on-hold) if I already have my answer and accepted it (posted by DLeh)? Some people need to stop power tripping!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Max X position:

```
lsRawPoints.Max(point => point.X)
```

Max Y Position

```
lsRawPoints.Max(point => point.Y)
```

Max Sum of components

```
lsRawPoints.Max(point => point.X + point.Y)
```

Etc.

Comment: +1. Another, sometimes necessary way is `lsRawPoints.OrderBy(p => p.X).Last()`.

Comment: @heltonbiker This is great. I get the x/y coordinate (XYPoint object) with the highest x value. Thank you everyone.

Answer (score 1):

You could use lambda function like the following.

```
    XYPoint maxx = lsRawPoints.OrderBy(t=>t.X).Last();//Max X value
    XYPoint maxy = lsRawPoints.OrderBy(t=>t.Y).Last();//Max Y value
```

Answer (score 1):

You use `Max` to find the maximum value of a collection. You can pass it a transform function like so:

```
lsRawPoints.Max(p => p.Y); //Gets maximum Y value
```

Which is similar to:

```
lsRawPoints.Select(p => p.Y).Max();
```

Either way, note that this is *still* iterating over (looping) the entire collection; so you didn't actually avoid the problem you stated in your question.

LINQ makes iteration more efficient by taking advantage of lazy execution/iteration, but if you iterate the whole collection anyways (as is required for `Max`), its just providing a more semantic function call for the loop you would have written yourself.

Comment: You are right, but Linq syntax is more elegant.

Comment: @NoBullMan Unquestionably more elegant. I was simply trying to make sure the OP understood that it is still looping (which seemed an important misconception I saw in the question).

Answer (score 1):

Personally I'd just use a `foreach` loop to avoid multiple passes on the list.

```
int maxX = int.MinValue;
int maxY = int.MinValue;

foreach (var point in lsRawPoints)
{
    if (point.X > maxX)
        maxX = point.X;
    if (point.Y > maxY)
        maxY = point.Y;
}
```